# How do DNS servers know the server for the lower level?

Tags: dns

Been trying to google this for over 30 minutes. Abundant are explanations of how you can eventually get the IP address for "www.google.com", via your local DNS resolver querying the root DNS server, then the .com DNS server, then google.com's nameserver.

My question is, how does each DNS server know the address (and IP) of the authoritative server for the next(lower) level?

1. How does a root DNS server know the address (and IP) of the .com TLD DNS server?
2. How does the .com TLD DNS server know the address (and IP) of the google.com nameserver?

Once my domain's nameserver is reached I'd imagine things are now known/configured by the domain owner (Similar to how I could manage my DNS records for a domain I own).

Answer (score 0):

There exist 13 so-called *root domain servers*, and your operating system knows their addresses. There is an [article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server) about this.

Comment: This does answer not either of the 2 questions.